# Why is there an AM or PM in the result of the script?

Tags: google-apps-script

`=IF('Patrol Logs'!$H:$H<'Patrol Logs'!$F:$F, ('Patrol Logs'!$H:$H+"24:00")-'Patrol Logs'!$F:$F, 'Patrol Logs'!$H:$H-'Patrol Logs'!$F:$F)`
The code above is working and functional, but whenever the duration is in the cell, it adds a PM or AM to it.

Anybody know how to fix?

Comment: Have you tried to apply data formatting on the cells?

Comment: No, but I will try that now, thx!

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

You can also set the format by using `TEXT`

`=TEXT( YOUR RESULT , "HH:mm")`